# "too heavily" vs "heavily enough"

Tags: meaning-in-context, quantifiers, too

1. It had been snowing too heavily for me to leave the house.

Use *enough*:

2. It had been snowing heavily enough for me to stay indoors.

> [image]

Source: *The Communicative Grammar of English Workbook* - Page 14

Why does the author change ***leave the house*** into ***stay indoors***?

I understand it (*too* carries negative meaning \ *enough* carries positive meaning) so I dislike the result or I hate it in

1. It is so difficult for me to leave the house due to the much snow.
2. Positive result (The snow came down to such extent that I couldn't go out, so I would rather stay at home).

Could you please give me another interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is this:

> It had been snowing too heavily for me to leave the house.

If you say:

> It had been snowing too heavily for me to stay indoors.

That has the *opposite* meaning of what you intend to say. It means it was snowing so heavily that you could not remain indoors (you had to go outside).

So you need to substitute something for too heavily. That substitution is **heavily enough** in your example:

> It had been snowing <strike>too</strike> **heavily enough** for me to stay indoors.

There are many other ways to express the same idea with very similar words, but if the only thing you can replace in the sentence is **too heavily**, and you can't make any other changes, then I suppose **heavily enough** is best.

IMHO, a better construct would be to use **so heavily that** and you wouldn't have to make any substitutions at all:

> It had been snowing so heavily that I could not leave the house.
>
> It had been snowing so heavily that I had to stay inside.

Comment: Thank you    So why the book does not mention  solution page 14   https://books.google.iq/books?id=nqIWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA14-IA22&dq=It+had+been+snowing+too+heavily+for+me+to+leave+the+house.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi64rHm_-j6AhXeh_0HHcdoCjYQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=It%20had%20been%20snowing%20too%20heavily%20for%20me%20to%20leave%20the%20house.&f=false

Comment: _All_ the sentences given there are examples of expressing the same idea in two different ways. They appear to be answers; you don't tell us what the original exercise was.

Comment: It is clearly obvious in front of your eyes. from the beginning I mentioned it  + link   Why does the author change ( leave the house into stay indoors?  (copied )

The Communicative Grammar of English Workbook - Page 14   Moreover, the photo = question + answer

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, so I revised my answer.